# OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Mulesoft

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-platform

I am working with mule HTTP request connector's authentication client credentials grant type.
By default it is sending content type as application/json.
Is there a way to override the default content type?

Thanks

Comment: To what request are you referring to exactly?

Comment: HTTP GET request and use default authentication option(client credentials grant type) provided in request connector to get the authentication key. By default authentication is sending content-type as application/json but the endpoint needs application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: You mean the request to the authorization server to get the token? And what exact version of Mule, HTTP connector and HTTP service are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this on the Transform Message compontent before the HTTP request.

Specify the output as such:

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="4ed801af-81a5-4072-941f-653c3fbd1666" >
    <ee:message >
        <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
            output application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            ---
            {
                resource: vars.resource,
                client_id: vars.clientId,
                client_secret: vars.clientSecret,
                grant_type: vars.grantType
            }]]>
        </ee:set-payload>
    </ee:message>
</ee:transform>
```

Note; You can choose what every output you want on the Tranform Message compontent

Here is a list of all [Supported Data Formats](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats)